# Flot upgrade to 8.1 graph not rendering in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, flot

I stripped down my code to a simple page including the flog plugin and jquery files, but am still unable to get the flot graphs to render in IE 7 and 8.  I may be missing something, but I am using flot 8.1(7.0 worked fine).

I cut it down to a simple page with the what I assume are the necessary scripts.  Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>        

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />        

        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/other/excanvas.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js'></script>    
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js'></script>    
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js'></script>
</head>
    <body class="smw ssDark">
        <div class="header">
            <div id="chart_activity" style="height:500px;" >
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>
        $("document").ready(function(){
            if($("#chart_activity").length > 0){

        var stuff = [], contacts = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i += 1) {
            stuff.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
            contacts.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
        }

        $.plot($("#chart_activity"), [ { data: stuff, label: "stuff"}, { data: contacts, label: "contacts"}], {xaxis: {show: true}, yaxis: { show: true}});

    }
    });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Forgot to mention, I get the following error in IE console:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'fillStyle' of undefined or null reference 
excanvas.js, line 230 character 5
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  Could you try replacing excanvas with FlashCanvas (http://flashcanvas.net) and see if that works?  Please open a new issue for this on Github (https://github.com/flot/flot/issues) with the results of that test and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for coming back with the answer slowly.  Apparently the downloaded version of excanvas that I had, was somehow different from the one the came with Flot.  Once I switched them out everything worked fine in IE 7/8.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your question, I don't think I would have figured this out otherwise =)